# Firefox stuck at Login operation with Selenium-Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium-ruby

I'm trying to execute Selenium-webdriver code written in Ruby for firefox. 
I'm using `firefox 45.0.1` because I use `ruby 2.1.10` and `Selenium-WEbdriver-2.53.4`

When I execute Selenium opens firefox, enters address and enters username and password and hits login button. 
But after that It stays there with loading symbol near login and also browser says

> Transferring data from 34.23.23.2

Selenium is stuck here for 5 minutes and then exists saying timeout and gives below error.

```
**1.1) Failure/Error:**

@browser.span(:text=>'Login').wait_while_present(10000)
      Net::ReadTimeout:
        Net::ReadTimeout
```

When I manually open firefox new tab when selenium opens the firefox and try to login manually, I see the same issue. But When I open firefox manually from desktop and login it works. Please tell me what I'm I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that some websites detect when a automated test is running and behave differently, also when selenium starts up it uses a default profile and when you open it manualy your profile is loaded. Cant say for sure that's your problem.